# Html table doesn't show in stimulsoft report viewer

Tags: html, reporting, stimulsoft

I create my html table and I want to show this table in stimulsoft viewer. I checked "Allow HTML Tags" and it shows almost all of HTML tags like 
  and etc. But I want to show Table tags.
My Stimulsoft version is 2015.2.0.0

```html
<table style="width:100%">
  <tr>
    <th>Firstname</th>
    <th>Lastname</th> 
    <th>Age</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Jill</td>
    <td>Smith</td> 
    <td>50</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Eve</td>
    <td>Jackson</td> 
    <td>94</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

These tags are not supported in the Stimulsoft Reports. There is a limited support of the HTML tags. You could get necessary information on the User Manual https://www.stimulsoft.com/en/documentation/online/user-manual/report_internals_html_tags.htm